# Damped sine wave based on Fibonacci ratio

Tags: matlab, octave, fibonacci, exponential

How can I make a damping / damped sine wave based on the Fibonacci ratio?

I can create a plot based of the Fibonacci ratios using Octave / Matlab see code I have below along with plot.

```
clear all,clf reset, clc,tic
more off

fib1=[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
fib2=[1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
y=fib1./fib2
x_end=size(fib1,2);
x=[1:x_end]
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Fib plot]

I'm trying to get the plot to look like a damped sin wave but based on the Fibonacci ratio.  See example damped plot.

Ps: I'm using Octave 4.0 which is like Matalb

[image: Damped sine wave]

Comment: So you’re trying to use the top plot as an envelope for a sine function? How about you interpolate it to create a finer-sampled version (using a spline iterpolation?), then simply multiply your sampled sine by it. I guess you want each Fibonacci value to span one sine period?

Comment: @CrisLuengo any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understood what you are looking for. Basically, the main concept behind this question is that the ratios of consecutive numbers extracted from the Fibonacci's sequence can approximate the [golden number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) (also known as `phi`) and that the higher you climb into the sequence, the closer `phi` can be approximated. Starting from this assumption, you want to show that the way these ratios relate to `phi` follows the pattern defined by a [damped sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damped_sine_wave).

---

The main problem of your plot derives from the fact there are too few points to be used for plotting, hence the resulting line looks segmented instead of showing the typical sinusoidal shape. Also, the sequence being offset by one (`fib2`) should be the one being divided by the other one (`fib1`), not the opposite... provided I didn't misunderstood your goal.

Given a range `x = 0:0.01:9` that contains enough points to allow the line to be plotted with the correct shape, let's start by building and plotting the wave itself:

```
x_max = 9;
x = 0:0.01:x_max;

gr = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
w = (gr - 2) .* exp(1 - x) .* cos(pi() .* x) + gr;
plot(x,w);

seq = 1:(x_max+2);
fib = fibonacci(seq);
p = fib(2:end) ./ fib(1:end-1);

y = NaN(size(x));
y(ismember(x,seq-1)) = p;

hold on;
plot(x,y,'or');
hold off;
```

Final output:

[image: Output]

---

If your only goal is to plot the wave you computed... as I previously said, the main problem is the lack of points. With only `8` points, the line loses its shape due to the poor precision. In order to solve it, write your code as follows ([spline](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html), as suggested by Cris, is a very good instrument in this situation):

```
fib1 = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
fib2 = [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34];
y = fib1 ./ fib2;
y = spline(0:7,y,0:0.01:7);

plot(y);
```